# Trying to get getopts to call a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, getopts

I'm trying to get it to call a function.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":a:b:" opt; do
    case $opt in 
        a)
            my_function "%e"
            ;;
        b)
            my_function "%s"
            ;;
       /?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
            ;;
    esac
done

my_function() {
    option=$1
    //do something here
}
```

When i call: `./myscript.sh -a sshd`

This would display `./myscript.sh: line 5: my_function: command not found`

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shell script to be able to call a function, that function has to have been defined before calling it.  This is not the case in your code.

To fix it, move the function to above the command line parsing loop.

Also, I would make the last `case` test be `*)` to catch any unhandled option (`/?` would never match a single option character).  And the `getopts` utility would already output an error message, so you don't need to repeat that (`$OPTARG` may additionally not be what you use here, but `$opt`).